# How to animate divs rendered by ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How to animate divs like in this [demo](http://jsbin.com/xejekijuka/1/edit?css,js,output), but animation must be when divs are filtering by ng-repeat filters.

**My code:**

```
<input class="filter_input" type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search">
<div ng-repeat="product in products | filter:search | filter:brand">

$scope.$watch('Products', function(){
   $scope.setOrder();
   calcGridPosition();
}, true);
```

There is no difference how to implement animation via ngAnimate or by custom method like in the demo.

Comment: Please see my updated solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You having to basically rebuild the list each time to force it to re-evaluate the grid.  If you just do ng-repeat with the original list, filtering out items doesn't actually modify the list.  The animation depends on the data stored in the list object.

http://jsbin.com/weyoxazajo/1/edit

I ended up creating this function:

```
$scope.queryList = function(query) {
  $scope.myList = [];
  $scope.myOriginalList.forEach(function(v, i) {
    if (v.text.indexOf(query) !== -1) {
  $scope.myList.push($scope.myOriginalList[i]);    
    }
  });
  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.order = 'random';
  $scope.setOrder();   
  }, 500);
};
```

It runs a quick search on the original dataset and pushes any matches to the array that is hooked in to ng-repeat.  It has to rebuild the array each time, recalculate the grid, then after a brief timeout, run the animation.

Because this particular animation runs off of the actual stored dataset, using ng-repeat's filter/orderBy capability isn't going to work.  You will have to pre-process the data with whatever filtering or ordering you want, then push it to the array that ng-repeat is hooked in to.  This is not ideal, but for this particular animation, that is how it is done.  Filtering functions aren't that difficult to create.

For other animations that work with ng-repeat using ng-animate, check the angular docs.  They have some a nice example that you can tinker with:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: Yes, but I need this animation works on ng-repeat's filtering/sorting thing. I can't make that work. I'm using $watch and $watchCollection services on array. Please see the updated question.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean **@tpie**! But how to use it, how to bind your function to ng-repeat filtering? That's the main problem)

Comment: That's what I am saying.  The way the thing was written, I don't believe you can without completely rewriting the animation.  What sort of filtering do you need to do?  All you have to do is modify that queryList function I made to handle whatever filtering you need to do and ng-repeat will then display it.

Comment: **@tpie**, I'm just filtering the array on search input. That's all) What I do not understand is how to make work your function on search input..( How to bind it to search input?

Comment: Look carefully at the bin - the search button fires off the function and gives it the text in the input as a search parameter.  Just do that and get rid of the filter on your ng-repeat.

Comment: ...seems to be working here.  It even works on my phone.  The search is case sensitive.  Enter 'o' and click search.

Comment: Yeh @tpie, seems it works) Do you know how to implement animation on divs positioned in columns in angular way? I mean using ng-enter, ng-leave classes. And, thank you!

Comment: No, not yet.  Looks like the way you would apply this sort of animation to a angular-way ng-repeat animation though.